# php export mysql chinese character to csv, but the character becomes garbage code

Tags: php, mysql, csv, export

I am trying to export data from mysql to csv which contains some chinese character, however it always become garbage code. I googled and find suggestion to add BOM at the heading.But it seems still not work, here is my code. please suggest.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["Export"]))
{   
mysql_connect('localhost','test','abc');
mysql_select_db('test');

header('Content-Encoding: UTF-8');
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8' );
header(sprintf( 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=my-csv-%s.csv', date( 'dmY-His' ) ) );
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');

$data = fopen( 'php://output', 'w' );

//This line is important:
fputs( $data, "\xEF\xBB\xBF");

fputcsv($data,array('student_id','student_chiName','student_engName','    student_title','student_gender','news_receive'));


//Retrieve the data from database
$rows = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM student');

//Loop through the data to store them inside CSV
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rows)){
fputcsv($data, $row);

}
}

?>
```

Here is my Hex view, seems chinese character are only one byte, one byte is missing. It seems PHP does not ouput the character in 4 bytes.
   [image: The hex dump of output file by PHP]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$data = fopen($filepath, 'w');
$rows = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM student');

fprintf($df, chr(0xEF).chr(0xBB).chr(0xBF));
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rows)){
    fputcsv($data, $row);
}
```

the line `fprintf($df, chr(0xEF).chr(0xBB).chr(0xBF));` writes file header for correct encoding.